# Determine Correct JSON Fields for REST API based on Endpoint and Screen names (Customers & Sales Orders) - Acumatica

Tags: rest, acumatica, acumatica-kb

My project is to import Customers and Sales orders. I take a CSV file from an external program, and am to import them -- field by field -- into Sales Orders and Customers.

My challenge is determining the correct field names to get the REST API to work correctly.

I have the following fields:

[image: Customer Screen]

I am looking to include the three fields: Description, Gift Message, and Public Comment. I inspect the element, which gives me nothing useful that I can tell. (i.e. none of the values map to the field name that I would use in JSON.)

When I go to the Endpoint for Customers, Description already exists:

[image: Endpoint Showing Description Field]

And therefore, this JSON Record succeeds in an ADD or UPDATE:

```
{
    "OrderNbr"  : {"value": "SO003525"},
    "Description"  : {"value": "This is the Description"},
}
```

I extend the default customer (version 18.200.001) and I find and add the "Gift Description" and the "Public Comments" -- and they are listed as part of the "Order Summary" -- which is exactly where Description was.

[image: Gift and Public Comment]

However, this JSON data does add anything to Gift or Public:

```
{
    "OrderNbr"  : {"value": "SO003525"},
    "Description"  : {"value": "This is the Description"},
    "PublicComment"  : {"value": "This is the Public Comment"},
    "GiftMessage": { "value": "This is the Gift Message"},
}
```

In talking to the (in-house) developer who set up the screen, he told me that the "Gift Message" and "Public Comments" fields were added on. But they are not showing as "User Defined" fields in the Endpoint.

Questions:

1) How can I know what the JSON structure should look like? Is there some sort of a mapping document, or a printout that shows JSON-to-Endpoint data? What I mean is that sometimes I need to use a sub-object to reference data in JSON, for example, if I want to update "Main Contact" information, I do it like this:

```
{
 "CustomerClass":{"value":"INDIVIDUAL"},
 "CustomerID":{"value":"78577"},
 "CustomerName":{"value":"TEST CUSTOMER "},
 "MainContact":
   {
     "CompanyName":{"value":"TEST CUSTOMER COMPANY"},  
     "DisplayName":{"value": "TEST CUSTOMER DISPLAY"}, 
   }
}
```

How can I know to do that? (I know only because I saw it in the data that got returned when I added a record... Which brings up a second question:

2) Is there a way for retrieving an entire data record in its JSON format. Sort of like a : "GET - SELECT ALL - EXPAND ALL" so I can see all of the data in a record in a properly set up JSON format?

3) Any idea why the gift Message and Public Comments are showing as "Order Summary" but aren't updating like Description is?

4) Why are some things "un-expandable?" For example, I cannot expand Payments in Sales Order. I get an error:

[image: Capture of Payments Expand Error]

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not use an Import Scenario for this since the source of the data is a .CSV file?

Comment: @JerryKurtz: Interesting question. I haven't seen a way of calling an Import Scenario via the API. Can you point me to that?

Comment: Sorry, not what I meant.  I guess I was just wondering why you would use the REST API for this task instead of just using a simple Import Scenario?

Comment: Ahhh... darn, I thought you knew a way of doing that! To your question, 2 reasons: First off, there is manipulation being done to the CSV file values. Secondly, we want this done on a scheduled interval, which means we don't want a user to have to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How can I know what the JSON structure should look like

The easiest way is to execute a GET request. The field names are equivalent to the `DisplayName` property stripped of whitespaces. So if on screen the field is labelled `Order Type` the field name will be `OrderType` in the request.

To make a GET request, the URL format is `/Entity/Keys`.

For example entity `SalesOrder` has two keys: `OrderType` and `OrderNbr`.

To get entity `SalesOrder` of type `SO` and with the number `SO005051` the URL would end with: `/SalesOrder/SO/SO005051`.

> 2) Is there a way for retrieving an entire data record in its JSON
>   format. Sort of like a : "GET - SELECT ALL - EXPAND ALL" so I can see
>   all of the data in a record in a properly set up JSON format?

If you want all the details, you need to specify them all in the expand clause of the GET query: `$expand=Contacts,MainContact,BillingContact`

The name of the details array can be looked up in the Web Service Endpoint screen SM207060. They are the tree view elements with a empty array `[]` suffix.

[image]

> 3) Any idea why the gift Message and Public Comments are showing as
>   "Order Summary" but aren't updating like Description is?

Those are custom fields. You need to extend the endpoint to add those custom fields otherwise they will be ignored. If there's no issue with the custom endpoint maybe the field aren't bound to database.

> But they are not showing as "User Defined" fields in the Endpoint.

If by `User Defined` you mean those fields were added with a wizard (without programming) then this is likely the reason why they don't work in the web service. You would need to add custom field with a DAC extension which requires programming instead of the User Defined field.

Comment: But, MainComment isn't an array. Why is it expandable? And when an array has no data, I get a blank back (i.e. expanding Shipments returns:  "Shipments": []) -- what I want to know is what fields are available in Shipments so I can have a Master JSON class that shows all possible fields. Does that make sense? (also can you look at the update to my question showing that I cannot expand Payments at all)

Comment: There's many ways you can build the list of fields, GET request on Shipment entity is one. You could also just go to the Fields tab of Shipment entity in web service endpoint screen . When there's no detail data (empty) you get an empty array. When the system says you can't expand (because of optimization) then you can't expand.

Comment: MainContact is a different entity then customer, it is the contact entity of the customer. It is not an expandable details array. In the response you will get a single entity {} when expanding it instead of an array. Also note that it is generally preferable to not work with all fields but restrict them with the select clause to reduce overhead on slow internet.

Comment: I understand the need to restrict fields. What I am trying to get is what I would call a mapping document. I have fields coming from a POS system. I want to know all of the places I have in Acumatica to receive them. I don't want all fields every time. I am just trying to build a master mapping document for reference. What I am sensing is that such a thing does not exist.

Comment: All the fields are configured in the "Web Service Endpoints" page in the Fields tab. I don't understand how you can conclude that it doesn't exists.